# How to use Azure AD for authenticate users for third-party applications?

Tags: rest, authentication, azure, oauth-2.0

I didn't touch AAD before, but I have to use it for authenticate users for my REST service.

I have a mobile client that can authenticate a user on AAD with OAuth2. As a result it has a bearer token. 
This bearer token mobile client should use as a parameter in a request for protected REST service.
REST service is a Java-based application (spring-boot) and it was registered in AAD as a Web application, but I can not find a way how it can connect to AAD for check is token valid or not. 
I expected to have something like **/oauth2/check_token** endpoint that can take a token value and return a user data, but I didn't find anything.

Is it possible to use AAD for authentication users for third-party applications and if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token issued by AAD is a signed JWT token. You do not need to communicate with AAD to verify the token is valid. If you trust the issuer (AAD) and the token is valid (correct audience, valid signature, not expired etc.), you accept the claims in the token.

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179819.aspx) for the steps to validate the JWT token.

Comment: Thank you, @MvdD, I really forgot about JWT